# Why are the lights in my 60 year old house flickering?

Tags: electrical

My lights will flicker throughout the house when I have a lot on.  Also, the ceiling fan will go (beep, beep BEEP beep) then reverse all by itself when the bathroom light is turned on down the hall.

This happens intermittently, day or evening, and especially if there has been rain.  We live near the coast.

Comment: What vintage is your electrical?  Circuit breakers or fuses?  When is the last time someone went through the circuit panel and tightened all the connectors?

Comment: Thank you, they are circuit breakers in a panel outside.  No one has ever tightened them @wallyk.

Comment: Unless there's some techniques I'm unaware of, the only way I know to switch a motors rotation, without special intervention to the motor itself, is switch any two legs in the panel or at some junction, but that's in a 3-phase system. Take Tester101's advice; you need someone on-site to help you with this.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It is probably because it is a smart fan that knows to switch direction if the switch is toggled quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Our house is old..1846 old. We had this issue in our home as well. All breakers were good, nothing was shorting out, tripping breakers, etc. 
First thing I did was call the power company. Turns out the service line connecting to our house was loose. They tightened it up free of charge and the problem stopped.
This can happen over time, after a storm with lots of wind, from a branch falling and catching it some, etc.
I'd have the power company check the service line and if it's all fine and good, then I'd call and electrician.

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient power would result in the lights just dimming when too many things are running or an appliance turns on. You'd also see a breaker periodically trip.

With your flickering, I suspect the problem is much more severe, possibly a short or arcing. And if it's either of those, it's a fire hazard. As Tester101 says in the comments, get an electrician that can diagnose and track down the issue.

As a DIYer, things that you could do to track this down yourself include testing each outlet to look for voltage swings when the flickering occurs. Attempt to isolate the flickering to a single circuit and check every junction on that circuit, particularly around points of the circuit where the flickering begins/ends. Rewire anything that uses push in connectors since older versions of these can become loose over time. If you believe it's weather related, check all outside outlets for moisture and/or corrosion and replace anything that shows damage with a weather tight covered outlet. I would also check the junctions at outdoor lights where water could intrude.

As always, when working with electrical, turn off the breaker and verify there is no hot wiring with an electrical tester (preferably the non-contact style) before touching any wires.

Answer (score 1):

Our lights flicker slightly whenever the A/C or the refrigerator starts. When a motor/compressor starts it drops the voltage on the line for an instant especially if your utility has you on a transformer with several of your neighbors. You could have a licensed/experienced Journeyman electrician check all your connections or use a FLIR camera to look for hotspots (bad connections).

The ceiling fan is another story. If it has electronic controls (the beeping) then it could reset to factory default direction when the voltage drops far enough to simulate loss of power. Requiring you to set it back to the other direction. I don't know of any way to reverse a standard ceiling fan by changing the voltage you have to use the switch.

I would have an electrician inspect the whole system and tell them all the problems you are having.